# How to make a common class for UINavigationController barbutton item actions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

In my app, i need to have a UINavigationController which will have different navigation bar in different view controllers and based on that it will have different UIBarButton items which will required different actions.

Currently what i have is a navigation controller and i am customizing it where ever required and if there are any buttons i need to add i am writing its action method in the same class. But at many places the action is similar so i want to create a common controller for this.
i know this is the inefficient way so i was thinking if somebody can guide me on how to make it more productive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the bar button item in a `UIViewController` base class is the right way to go.

In the base class:

```
// Configure button.
button.target = self;
button.action = @selector(action:);


// Implement common action.
- (void)action:(id)sender {
    …
}
```

In subclass with special action:

```
// Implement special action.
- (void)action:(id)sender {
    …
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say i should create a UIviewController which contains all the possible actions and then every viewController should inherit this? and what about changing the navigation bar in every viewcontroller?

Comment: Just for common bar button items with "similar actions" — according to your question post.